# DELL Powerconnect 5324 SSH

Tags: switch, ip, ssh, dell

it sounds a bit strange, but how can i find out the IP Address which i can connect to? The Switch works fine, but i need to do some changes. 
I have console access to it, but i want it, because it's more comfortable, to do over SSH.

rsa & dsa keys are generated und ip ssh server enabled.

Now I only need to know which IP address the Switch has. It is our only DELL Switch in the company. The others are Cisco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look in the configuration of `interface vlan 1` (in a "`show running-config`" result)

If there's no IP address under interface vlan 1, then you can configure it with the following commands (thanks to [Steve Jenkins](http://www.stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/05/dell-powerconnect-5324-setup-tasks/))

```
console> enable
console# config
console# interface vlan 1
console(config-if)# ip address 192.168.1.222 /24
console(config-if)#ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
console(config-if)# exit
config(config)# exit
console#
```

You will find the manual at [this Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/powerconnect-5324/manuals)

Comment: Thanks. Works. Dumb thing is, when I get myself a IP in the same subnet i can't go online because of the configuration. But i can live withit! I am happy not to configure it in the serverroom. Thanks!

Comment: This is an example of a basic configuration, you can also configure an IP on the switch in another vlan if it better fits your network addressing.

Comment: There is ah configuration on it. An no longer employee has set it up. The VLAN1 IP is 172.16.16.62 in my Case. And the LAN i am normally working on hast the IP 192.0.0.0/24.

Comment: It really depends of your overall enterprise network configuration. If other systems use an IP in the 192.0.0.0/24 network in the VLAN 1 and the 172.16.16.0/X network is not used anywhere else you should be fine to change the IP of the Dell switch, but you need to have a good overview of the network.

Comment: I am actually really confused, because Port 1 (g1) has Gateway IP 172.16.16.1. But if plugin my PC and say use DHCP. I get an IP assigned from the 192.0.0.0-network. How does this work? I'm really new to network administration. I know that the switch is connected to a Port on a Cisco router with IP 192.0.0.1. This port has no VLAN configuration. Just physical IP assigned etc. But that's actually offtopic to this question but i don't want to spam hundreds of questions ...